# Programmatically collapse a group in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

When I expand a new group, can I collapse the last one expanded?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Try putting this in your `ExpandableListAdapter`, `listView` is a reference to the `ExpandableListView` itself. And `lastExpandedGroupPosition` is a integer member variable defined inside your `ExpandableListAdapter`.

```
    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition){
        //collapse the old expanded group, if not the same
        //as new group to expand
        if(groupPosition != lastExpandedGroupPosition){
            listView.collapseGroup(lastExpandedGroupPosition);
        }

        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);           
        lastExpandedGroupPosition = groupPosition;
    }
```

Comment: No problem.  Did this for an app a while back.  Glad it could help someone else.

Comment: There is a problem with your solution: the new expanded group will be scrolled as far as the height of the last group (which is closed). But thanks anyway.

Comment: To avoid keeping a instance variabel called lastExpandedGroupPosition you can simply loop over your whole lists index, and then close all which isn't the new group that is getting expanded.

Comment: @JohanS isn't that overkill?To prevent keeping an int you loop through a potentially huge list

Answer (score 23):

Very helpful, but as [Anh Tuan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/470160/anh-tuan) mentions in the comments above, I was having problems with the ExpandableListView not then scrolling back to the top of the currently selected group (it would stay at the currently scrolled position, in the middle of the group somewhere). You also need to add an onGroupClickListener() to scroll to the correct position:

```
@Override
public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,
        long id) {
    // Implement this method to scroll to the correct position as this doesn't
    // happen automatically if we override onGroupExpand() as above
    parent.smoothScrollToPosition(groupPosition);

    // Need default behaviour here otherwise group does not get expanded/collapsed
    // on click
    if (parent.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {
        parent.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
    } else {
        parent.expandGroup(groupPosition);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hey groupPosition is always return zero can you guide me

Comment: Even though this technically does the trick, it doesn't look pretty. Any recommendations to make it look better?

Comment: Okay I'm answering my own question. If you call parent.setSelection(groupPosition) it looks much better. Keep in mind, it needs to be called after group expanding or collapsing logic, not before.

Answer (score 17):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586174/collapse-all-group-except-selected-group-in-expandable-listview-android/17586315?noredirect=1#17586315) worked for me

```
expandableList.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {
    int previousItem = -1;

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
        if(groupPosition != previousItem )
            expandableList.collapseGroup(previousItem );
        previousItem = groupPosition;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Do this to expand the clicked group and collapse all others

```
public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (i != groupPosition)
        {
            expandableListDetailsLevel.collapseGroup(i);
        }
    }
}
```

It's working for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
        for(int i=0;i<mGroupCollection.size();i++){
            if(i==groupPosition){
                System.out.println("Nothing");
                         }
            else{
                   mExpandableListView.collapseGroup(i);
            }

        }
        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    }
```