# Expandable List: Android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I m working on android. i have made expandable list view and its working properly. I have given 4 group rows in the same activity.. I want to close first expandable list automatically when i click on other. is it possible?? Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this must help you: [Programmatically collapse a group in ExpandableListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314777/programmatically-collapse-a-group-expandablelistview).