# How to get position of Third level Expandable ListView?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I need the groupPositon and ChildPosition of SecondLevel and ThirdLevel Expandable ListView particularly. I need to add OnClick event based on the group position and also the childposition value with reference to the data items given in the LinkedHashmap or Array

```
  ExpandableListView expListView,expandableListView;
public static String[] parent = new String[]{"Rooms","Lighting","Accessories","Rugs","Gift Cards"};
String[] q1 = new String[]{"Living Room", "Dining Room","Bed Room","Kitchen","Outdoor Living"};

String[] des1 = new String[]{"Living Room Sets","Sofas & LoveSeats","Sectional Sofas","Sofa Sleeper","Pillows","Chairs","Coffee & End tables","Table Sets","Consoles & Desks","TV Consoles","Ottoman","Accent tables","Chaises","Pouf","Recliners","Serving Carts","Stools"};
 setUpAdapter();

String[] des2=new String[]{};


//level 3
LinkedHashMap<String, String[]> thirdLevelq1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
LinkedHashMap<String, String[]> thirdLevelq2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
LinkedHashMap<String, String[]> thirdLevelq3 = new LinkedHashMap<>();

LinkedHashMap<String, String[]> thirdLevelq4 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
LinkedHashMap<String, String[]> thirdLevelq5 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
List<String[]> secondLevel = new ArrayList<>();
 private void setUpAdapter() {

        secondLevel.add(q1);
        secondLevel.add(q1);
        secondLevel.add(q1);
        secondLevel.add(q1);
        secondLevel.add(q1);


        thirdLevelq1.put(q1[0], des1);
        thirdLevelq1.put(q1[1], des1);
        thirdLevelq1.put(q1[2], des1);
        thirdLevelq1.put(q1[3], des1);
        thirdLevelq1.put(q1[4], des1);

    thirdLevelq2.put(q1[0], des2);
    thirdLevelq2.put(q1[1], des2);
    thirdLevelq2.put(q1[2], des2);
    thirdLevelq2.put(q1[3], des2);
    thirdLevelq2.put(q1[4], des2);

    thirdLevelq3.put(q1[0], des2);
    thirdLevelq3.put(q1[1], des2);
    thirdLevelq3.put(q1[2], des2);
    thirdLevelq3.put(q1[3], des2);
    thirdLevelq3.put(q1[4], des2);

    thirdLevelq4.put(q1[0], des2);
    thirdLevelq4.put(q1[1], des2);
    thirdLevelq4.put(q1[2], des2);
    thirdLevelq4.put(q1[3], des2);
    thirdLevelq4.put(q1[4], des2);

    thirdLevelq5.put(q1[0], des2);
    thirdLevelq5.put(q1[1], des2);
    thirdLevelq5.put(q1[2], des2);
    thirdLevelq5.put(q1[3], des2);
    thirdLevelq5.put(q1[4], des2);


        data.add(thirdLevelq1);
        data.add(thirdLevelq2);
        data.add(thirdLevelq3);
        data.add(thirdLevelq4);
        data.add(thirdLevelq5);




    final ThreeLevelListAdapter threeLevelListAdapterAdapter = new ThreeLevelListAdapter(this, parent, secondLevel, data);
        expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandible_listview);
        //passing three level of information to constructor

        expandableListView.setAdapter(threeLevelListAdapterAdapter);

        expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int groupsPosition, int childsPosition, long id) {
                //String data =listDataChild.get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
                String[] value=secondLevel.get(0);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+value,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                return false;
            }
        });
        expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
            int previousGroup = -1;

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                if (groupPosition != previousGroup)
                    expandableListView.collapseGroup(previousGroup);
                previousGroup = groupPosition;
            }
        });


    }
```

Here is my SecondLevelAdapter

```
 public class SecondLevelAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context context;


List<String[]> data;

String[] headers;

ImageView ivGroupIndicator;


public SecondLevelAdapter(Context context, String[] headers, List<String[]> data) {
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
    this.headers = headers;

}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {

    return headers[groupPosition];
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {

    return headers.length;
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_second, null);

    TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowSecondText);
    ImageView img_selection=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivGroupIndicator);
    String groupText = getGroup(groupPosition).toString();
    text.setText(groupText);
    int imageResourceId = isExpanded ? R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_up_black_24dp
            : R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp;
    img_selection.setImageResource(imageResourceId);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {

    String[] childData;

    childData = data.get(groupPosition);


    return childData[childPosition];
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_third, null);

    TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowThirdText);
    String[] childArray = data.get(groupPosition);
    String text = childArray[childPosition];
    textView.setText(text);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    String[] children = data.get(groupPosition);
    return children.length;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
}
```

here is my thirdLevelAdapter

```
 public class ThreeLevelListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

String[] parentHeaders;
List<String[]> secondLevel;
private Context context;
List<LinkedHashMap<String, String[]>> data;

/**
 * Constructor
 * @param context
 * @param parentHeader
 * @param secondLevel
 * @param data
 */
public ThreeLevelListAdapter(Context context, String[] parentHeader, List<String[]> secondLevel, List<LinkedHashMap<String, String[]>> data) {
    this.context = context;
    this.parentHeaders = parentHeader;
    this.secondLevel = secondLevel;
    this.data = data;
}
@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return parentHeaders.length;
}
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    // no idea why this code is working
    return 1;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int i) {
    return null;
}

public Object getGroup(String[] groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}
@Override
public Object getChild(int group, int child) {
    return child;
}
@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}
@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}
@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_first, null);
    TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowParentText);
    text.setText(this.parentHeaders[groupPosition]);
    return convertView;
}
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final SecondLevelExpandableListView secondLevelELV = new SecondLevelExpandableListView(context);
    String[] headers = secondLevel.get(groupPosition);
    List<String[]> childData = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String, String[]> secondLevelData = data.get(groupPosition);
    for (String key : secondLevelData.keySet()) {
        childData.add(secondLevelData.get(key));
    }
    secondLevelELV.setAdapter(new SecondLevelAdapter(context, headers, childData));
    secondLevelELV.setGroupIndicator(null);
    secondLevelELV.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
        int previousGroup = -1;
        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            if (groupPosition != previousGroup)
                secondLevelELV.collapseGroup(previousGroup);
            previousGroup = groupPosition;
        }
    });
    return secondLevelELV;
}
@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37777455/3946958

Comment: Refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52309469/android-multilevel-expandable-list-view-set-third-level-child-item-clicked/52427456#52427456