# Collapse all group except selected group in expandable listview android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm developing android application using expandable list view. Actually what I need is, I'm listing group, which contains child.

If I select an unexpandable group, it should expand, after I ll select second group at that time the first group should be collapsed. I did Google, but I couldn't find what I want. Please help me out.

Answer (score 210, accepted):

Have the current expanded group position stored in a variable. In onGroupExpanded do the following.

```
private int lastExpandedPosition = -1;
private ExpandableListView lv; //your expandable listview
...

lv.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            if (lastExpandedPosition != -1
                    && groupPosition != lastExpandedPosition) {
                lv.collapseGroup(lastExpandedPosition);
            }
            lastExpandedPosition = groupPosition;
    }
});
```

Comment: hello user936414, i feel good that I give you 100th reputation point. Thanks for answer.

Comment: If the ExpandableListView has more than 2 groups, it will not close all groups

Comment: @HassanTareq As `expandableListView` do not have its groups open by default, You would get the desired work by collapsing the previously opened group.

Comment: @user936414 This makes the expandablelstview to scroll to the end or middle of the expanded group. Any solution?

Comment: Hi, how can i implement this above code on a custom made list view with a child group as a relative layout

Answer (score 29):

Use this code this will work

```
expandableList.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {
    int previousItem = -1;

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
        if(groupPosition != previousItem )
            expandableList.collapseGroup(previousItem );
        previousItem = groupPosition;
    }
});
```

Comment: but in this case, it's lose the focus on current group..Please help me for that

Comment: This line `int previousItem = -1;` needs to be placed outside the method. Or `previousItem` will be reset each time (vanishing this later instruction: `previousItem = groupPosition;`)

Comment: This method has a flaw. It doesn't scroll to the top of the expanded group as it would do without the collapseGroup call. It is the case when the expanded group is BELOW the collapsed group. The view scrolls to the place where the expanded group would be if the old group hasn't be collapsed. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @Dark.Rider I am having the same issue. Did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 8):

```
@Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition){
        //collapse the old expanded group, if not the same
        //as new group to expand
        if(groupPosition != lastExpandedGroupPosition){
            listView.collapseGroup(lastExpandedGroupPosition);
        }

        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);           
        lastExpandedGroupPosition = groupPosition;
    }
```

Comment: Method name is misspelled, and there is no super AFAICT.

Answer (score 5):

If the ExpandableListView has more than 2 groups:

```
expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
        for (int g = 0; g < expandableListAdapter.getGroupCount(); g++) {
            if (g != groupPosition) {
                expandableListView.collapseGroup(g);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

It will collapse all groups except the clicked one.

Comment: there is no method like getGroupCount() in expandable list view??

Comment: If you really look close, you can see the method is on the adapter

Answer (score 3):

Get `ExpendableListView` and then override the following method - `setOnGroupExpandListener`

```
expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.exp_listview);

expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
        int previousItem = -1;

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            if (groupPosition != previousItem)
                expandableListView.collapseGroup(previousItem);
            previousItem = groupPosition;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this in your ExpandableListAdapter, listView is a reference to the ExpandableListView itself. And lastExpandedGroupPosition is a integer member variable defined inside your ExpandableListAdapter.

```
 @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition)

{

//collapse the old expanded group, if not the same

//as new group to expand

if(groupPosition != lastExpandedGroupPosition)

{

  listView.collapseGroup(lastExpandedGroupPosition);

  }

        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);           
        lastExpandedGroupPosition = groupPosition;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   elstListView1.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            for(int i=0;i<listDataHeader.size();i++){
                if(i==groupPosition){
                    //do nothing}
                    else{
                        elstListView1.collapseGroup(i);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -5):

I also faced the same problem. But I could solved my problem by the following code:

As I had 4 Headers in my expandable list, based on that i wrote like this

```
expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPos) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                expListView.collapseGroup(groupPos+1);
                expListView.collapseGroup(groupPos-1);
                expListView.collapseGroup(groupPos-2);
                expListView.collapseGroup(groupPos+2);
                expListView.collapseGroup(groupPos+3);
                expListView.collapseGroup(groupPos-3);
            }
        });`
```