# setOnGroupExpandListener is not resolved, android

Tags: java, android

I followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586174/collapse-all-group-except-selected-group-in-expandable-listview-android) and the answer with most results gives me that the method, setOnGroupExpandListener cannot be resolved. I'm new to android and currently doing stuff basically by checking out how others have done it and try to learn from them.

```
ExpendableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
private int lastExpandedPosition = -1;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
        if (lastExpandedPosition != -1
                && groupPosition != lastExpandedPosition) {
            expListView.collapseGroup(lastExpandedPosition);
        }
        lastExpandedPosition = groupPosition;
    }
});
```

This is in my MainActivity.java, setOnGroupExpandListener is underlined and "not resolved".

These are the imported classes:

```
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
```

This is the content of my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.kevin.ha1kattai"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
}
```

This is my project [file](http://kevin.planet.ee/files/HA1KATTAI.rar)

Comment: Did you do the correct import ? try deleting the import for ExpandablelistView & do this to import Ctrl+Shift+O

Comment: I added my imported clases. I did try your method aswell as it did not give results. Although, i had my own idea, i'm currently using Android 2.3.3 Gingerbread. Could this be that it's not defined in this version?

Comment: on hover of that red line what message it gives ?

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'setOnGroupExpandListener'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) Support **Min SDK:10**. Please change Your`minSdkVersion` .

**`android:minSdkVersion`**
An integer designating the minimum API Level required for the application to run.

Please set **minSdkVersion** as **13 or 17** for better approach

**Edited**

```
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.kevin.ha1kattai"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Comment: @Banana is your min SDk is not 10 ? If not then this is the answer

Comment: So following [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465049/changing-api-level-android-studio) link should give me are result I want?

Comment: @Banana whats your minSdkVersion version ?? i guess 10 .It will be better if you set 17 or 15

Comment: Added my build.gradle file, this android:minsdk goes into manifest, right?

Comment: @Banana set min as 15 for testing case.Let me inform

Comment: I changed the defaultConfig as you edited, also put the minSdk in android manifest, synced the gradle, rebuilt project but still i'm getting the same error.

Comment: I added my project file in the end as a .rar in case it could clear things out.

Comment: no need to add <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" /> (Remove this from manifest)

Comment: Removing this from manifest didn't change a thing. As i opened the module (F4) it shows that my version has been upgraded tho, so maybe the problem is in something else?

Comment: Hey @IntelliJAmiya. I figured the solution out - my listener method was before setAdapter and not in onCreate method. Although i'd like to give you a credit for your effort and help!

Comment: @Banana It running smoothly in here .Please upgrade your sdk manager (and properly set sdk path)

Comment: @Banana Glad to hear that