# ExpandableListview OnGroupClickListener Not Firing

Tags: android, expandablelistview, onclicklistener, expandablelistadapter

I'm following this: [Programmatically collapse a group in ExpandableListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314777/programmatically-collapse-a-group-in-expandablelistview). I want the user capable to expand only one group at a time and smoothly scroll to the right position. I've written a custom adapter that implements OnGroupClickListener:

```
public class CategoriesListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter implements OnGroupClickListener {

    private ExpandableListView expListView;
    private int lastExpandedGroupPosition = -1;

    // I get the expListView in the constructor...

    @Override
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View view, int groupPosition, long id) {

        parent.smoothScrollToPosition(groupPosition);

        if (parent.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {
            parent.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
        } else {
            parent.expandGroup(groupPosition);
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {

        if (groupPosition != lastExpandedGroupPosition) {
            expListView.collapseGroup(lastExpandedGroupPosition);
        }

        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
        lastExpandedGroupPosition = groupPosition;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the onGroupClick event is never fired...(I've put some logs inside the method). I've also tried:

```
expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View view, int groupPosition, long id) {
        // Same as above...
    });
}
```

Same results for this alternative...any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you to check for the imports first (not shown in your question),and make sure you have imported `android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener`

or replace : `new OnGroupClickListener() {`

with `new android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener {`

**EDIT :**

I also noticed that you are returning 'true' at the body of `boolean onGroupClick(...)`  that means "the click was handled" and groups will never be collapsed, expanded.

You should return false if you want to expand.So I suggest you to do like this :

```
expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
                Log.d("onGroupClick:", "worked");

                parent.smoothScrollToPosition(groupPosition);

                if (parent.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {
                    parent.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
                } else {
                   parent.expandGroup(groupPosition);
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: You can refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener.html)

Comment: Imports are correct. If I set return to false, the group is not being correctly collapsed at the first click (I need 2 click) and no event at all is being fired. Anyway, why the onGroupClickListener override on the adapter doesn't work? Last one: why the scroll is smooth on 4.3 and too fast on 2.3.3?