# How to implement Click Listener in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have a custom adapter, which extends `BaseExpandableListAdapter`.

I want my `ExpandableList` to expand and collapse when I'm clicking some `TextView`.

How should I implement it?

I suppose, i have to add `OnClickListener` to methods `getGroupView` and `getChildView`. And I see, there is boolean flag `isExpanded`.

So it should look like this:

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, final boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isExpanded){

               //What should i write here?
            }
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

But what should I write in `OnClickListener`? I cannot find any functions, which allow me to expand/collapse my listview.

Is there any function like `listView.expandGroup(itemPosition);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There actually is an [ExpandableListView.expandGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#expandGroup(int)). And it's reverse action [collapseGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#collapseGroup(int)).

If the `TextView` you are referring to is inside a listview item, then you are correct to the action inside an `onClickListener` inside the adapter. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314777/programmatically-collapse-a-group-in-expandablelistview) talks about expanding an `ExpandableListView` dynamically, I think you can just get the idea and reverse the action in order to do what you are aiming for.

Hope this helps. Cheers! :D

Comment: The main problem is that I have a 3-level expandable list. So i have a `ParentAdapter` and `ChildAdapter`. Inside Parent I create my custom `ExpendableList` and setting it to a `ChildAdapter`: 
`expList.setAdapter(new ChildAdapter(...);`

Comment: By `ParentAdapter` is it for the `GroupHeader`s and the `ChildAdapter` is for the items inside the `Group`?

Comment: Yes, you got it totally right.
So I need to use `collapseGroup` method inside `ChildAdapter`, but I dont know how to transfer my custom `ExpandableList` to my `ChildAdapter`.

Comment: Hmm.. You can simply pass a reference of your `ExpandableListView` in your `ChildAdapter` constructor, then use it accordingly from inside. :)

Comment: Oh man, you are my savior, how could I be so blind. It's the most obvious option possible. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to be of help. Happy coding. Cheers! :D

Answer (score 0):

The TextView you want to works as expand or collapse button for a group when you click on it must be a header of the ExpandableListViewAdapter.

Also you have setOnGroupExpandListener, and setOnGroupCollapseListener that triggers when a group is expanded or collapsed.